# How do I get Eclipse to show me a method's signature while typing?

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete

Basically I have code completion working (to the best of my knowledge that it 'works') in Eclipse, but it's not nearly as good as what Visual Studio has. I have it set to call auto-complete when ( is pressed, but doing this does not show a list of the method parameters. I have to mouse over the method for that to happen, and I'd prefer for it to happen while I type, like Intellisense in VS.

I'm using Aptana 3 with PyDev if it's relevant.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of looking for a better Python IDE, for exactly this reason. I've found that you can get close to a VS experience in PyCharm with assert statements---it's a bit of a pain to write another line of code so that code completion works, but my guess is that this is the only way that such a thing can be done in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in eclipse is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, as Jonas Karlsson said.